# Transform the following function into its second order cone form

Tags: second-order-cone-programming

I would like to transform the following function into its second order cone form but I do not know how to do that
$$f_\sigma(s)=\frac{\|s\|_2^2}{\|s\|_2^2+\sigma}$$

Thans a lot if you can help me !

Comment: If I understand [Second-order cone programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming), this is an optimization problem with constraints. On your case what are you looking to optimize and under what constraints?

Comment: I would like to model this optimisation problem on Julia but I do not know how to express the objective which is the minimisation of$ f_{\sigma}(s)$                                             
$$
\begin{array}{l}\operatorname{Min} \sum_{i=1}^{I} t_{i} \\ \text { s.t. } \quad m_{j}=\Phi \cdot \Psi \cdot \hat{x}_{j}, \quad j=1, \ldots, J \\ \frac{\|\hat{x}\|_{2}}{\|\hat{x}\|_{2}+\sigma} \leq t_{i}, \quad i=1, \ldots, I\end{array}
$$